# Active Directory Group members

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have retrieve all the users in a groups if the group contains nested groups i am trying to iterate over them separately and getting the users using another method.

What if the nested group again contains another nested group it would be redundant to create another method to fetch users again

I want to get all the users of a group including the nested group advise

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the `tokenGroups` attribute of the user account. Here's a blog post that might get you started - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2007/06/18/sample-java-application-that-retrieves-group-membership-of-an-active-directory-user-account.aspx

Comment: This will retrieve the group membership of the user but what i am looking is a vise versa I have to retrieve the members of the group and nested groups

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, perhaps you should try a query like:

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

This will [Resolve all members (including nested) security groups](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+Group+Related+Searches-ResolvesAllMembersIncludingNestedSecurityGroupsRequiresAtLeastWindows2003SP2) (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2).
You could then inquire if they are users or Groups.

A query like:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Will retrieve only user that are members of a group.

Comment: i am trying the same thing but not able to get all users from the nested group, only getting few users from each group I am getting. For more detail look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800718/not-able-to-fetch-users-form-active-directory