# Not able to fetch users form Active directory

Tags: java, windows, active-directory

I need to get all users which is present inside a group. I have suppose group G1 and inside that I have two sub group Like sg1 , sg2 and these two group is having users which i want to fetch.

> This is what I am using but only getting sg1 and sg2 but not users inside this

```
searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=*)(memberOf="+distinguishedName+"))"
```

can someone please help how can I get users inside sg1 and sg2.Let me know if more information is required.Thanks!!

**Update :**

I am trying to do this using java.

By applying below filter I am able to fetch users but not all, few users from each child group.

```
> searchFilter =
> "(&(|(objectClass=group)(objectClass=user))(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:="+distinguishedName+"))"
```

Comment: The programming/scripting language being used is not tagged; also, I believe you'd have to go deeper than this trivial approach to enumerate members of groups being a member of parent group.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful its java. I think by applying LDAP filters we can get the desired output but I am new to this. If not filter then what i can try?

Comment: Don't know what the query returns all the objects (recursively) or only direct children. If it's the latter you'll have to create some code/queries that iterates through all group objects and gets users. Or if possible specify the query to recursively look for objects (don't know if possible, although common sense tells me that it should be).

Answer (score 0):

Resolves all members (including nested) Security Groups (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2)

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Or to retrieve only users that are members:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

There are [known to work ldap queries](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+Group+Related+Searches-AllGroups). Be sure you have proper permissions in Microsoft Active Directory to perform the queries.

You can test these with an LDAP Browser. Something like [Apache Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

Comment: Thanks jwilleke, but what is happening , when passing parent group then only getting few members of child groups and when passing child group I am getting all users belongs to child group. So I don't think its has to do with Security group.